# how to use html codes in angular2 app

Tags: angular, typescript

I need a space character inside an element, 
in normal html file &nbsp is fine, but when I use it in angular2 component it prints raw string "&nbsp" I made some search on net and created a inner property of cmponent and set it '&nbsp'  but still dont work

template(app.component.html):

```
<li><a class="active-nav" href="index.html">MenuItem1<span>{{innerHTML}}</span></a>
```

component(app.component.ts):

```
export class AppComponent {
  innerHTML;
  constructor(){
    this.innerHTML='&nbsp';//I also tried ' ' not work
  }
```

how can I solve it ?

Comment: post it as answer :)

Comment: Although this is not your mani problem, It's `&nbsp;` (with a semi-colon), not `&nbsp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `innerHTML` binding like this:

```
<span [innerHTML]="innerHTML"></span>
```